# Why does $1-\sqrt{1-4pq} = 1-|p-q |$ for $p \in (0,1)$ and $q=1-p$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Why does $1-\sqrt{1-4pq} = 1-|p-q |$ for $p \in (0,1)$ and $q=1-p$ ?

How can I factor $1-\sqrt{1-4pq}$ to prove the above identity ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Subsitute $q=1-p$ into both sides. Notice then the equality you need to prove, and it will be immediate to you why it is true.